Relaunch failed kernels at runtime
I'm running a local calculation that takes around 4 days to complete. After the first time, I noticed that it started on 16 kernels but subsequently some of those kernels failed (and the workload was transfered to other kernels). Unfortunately I didn't save the error message. In the end there were 9 kernels left.
My current setup is this:
Table[parallelizedCommand[parameterSet[[i]]], {i, n}]

I'd like to restart failed kernels for each new parameter set.  I tried to run LaunchKernels[] and I'm getting the message:

LaunchKernels::nodef: Some subkernels are already running. Not launching default kernels again.

Running $KernelCount afterwards shows 9. Is there a way to restart the failed kernels on the fly or do I need to QuitKernel->StartKernel?
The parallel kernel status shows 9 kernels running, idle  and the parallel settings are
Evaluation failure handling: [x] retry [ ] abandon
[x] try to relaunch failed kernels
[x] enable parallel monitoring tools
[ ] forward cloud credentials
Parallel Kernel configuration:
Total number of configured kernels: 16
